# MPI program freezing during MPI_Recv

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm a beginner in MPI parallel programming. I've written this little piece of code to draw the Mandelbrot fracta. The idea is that the first slave will calculate the first half, stick it in a pointer, and send it to master node who is waiting for receiving pointer. The same thing happens for the second node. Finally, the master node should have the result in 2 different variables and will write them in one file.

```
......
    if((itertab=malloc((sizeof(int)*sizebuffre))) == NULL) { 
        printf("ERREUR , errno : %d (%s) .\n",errno,strerror(errno)); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    } 
    int rank, size,start,end;

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv); /* starts MPI */ 
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); /* get current process id */ 
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); /* get number of processes */
    MPI_Status st;

    /*allocation du tableau de pixel*/ 
    if (rank==1) { 
        xpixel = 0; 
        end = (nbpixelx/MACHINE_NUM); 
        Calcule(xpixel,end); 
        printf("rank 1 start : %d, end : %d\n",xpixel,end); 
        MPI_Send(&itertab,sizebuffre,MPI_INT,0,5,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        free(itertab); 
        printf("work done : i am rank 1 \n"); 
    } 
    if (rank==2) {
        xpixel = (nbpixelx/MACHINE_NUM); 
        end = nbpixelx; 
        Calcule(xpixel,end); 
        printf("rank 2 start : %d, end : %d\n",xpixel,end); 
        MPI_Send(&itertab,sizebuffre,MPI_INT,0,6,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        printf("work done : i am rank 2 \n"); 
        free(itertab); 
    }

    if (rank==0) { 
        if((itertabA=malloc((sizeof(int)*sizebuffre))) == NULL) { 
            printf("ERREUR d'allocation de itertabA, errno : %d (%s) .\n",errno,strerror(errno)); 
            return EXIT_FAILURE; 
        } 
        if((itertabB=malloc((sizeof(int)*sizebuffre))) == NULL) { 
            printf("ERREUR d'allocation de itertabB, errno : %d (%s) .\n",errno,strerror(errno)); 
            return EXIT_FAILURE; 
        }
        printf("test before reciving result from first slave\n");
        MPI_Recv(itertabA,sizebuffre,MPI_INT,1,5,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&st); 
        printf("result recived  rank 1 \n"); 
        MPI_Recv(itertabB,sizebuffre,MPI_INT,2,6,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&st); 
        printf("result recived rank 2 \n");



    }

    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

The problem is that my code freezes in the line where the master receives the result from first slave, but I don't know why?

I tried to debug the result. I added some printf to see where it freezes. This is the result:

```
test before reciving result from first slave
test in calcule function
trairment xpixel 0
trairment xpixel 1
trairment xpixel 2
...snip...
trairment xpixel 399
test after the end off calculating loop
rank 1 start : 0, end : 400
^C
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Overall, you question was not bad (especially for a beginner in your non-native language), however there were a few things that I've improved in your question that you could use to improve future questions. Take a look at the edits so you can learn for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MPI code is not working properly, because you are passing the wrong argument to `MPI_Send`. Your variable `itertab` is already a pointer to  your data buffer, you thus don't need to de-reference it again.

Instead of:

```
MPI_Send(&itertab,sizebuffre,MPI_INT,0,5,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

do:

```
MPI_Send(itertab,sizebuffre,MPI_INT,0,5,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Another issue is that you are accessing non allocated memory, both in your `Calcule` function, and in the output loop. In the `Calcule` function, you are writing into `itertab[xpixel*nbpixely+ypixel]=iter`. This will fail for process `2`, since it allocates only its local part of the `itertab` buffer. You'll need to subtract an offset for `xpixel`.

In the output loop, you are reading `itertabB` with the global index. Here, you should also subtract an offset for `xpixel`, like so:

```
fprintf(file,"%f %f %d\n", x, y,itertabB[(xpixel-(nbpixelx/MACHINE_NUM))*nbpixely+ypixel]);
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response, i really apreciate that.
for the first issue, it's clear, i 've got my mistake, but i didn't see what you mean for the seconde issue, in the calclue function, thing should be like this ??

itertab[(xpixel-(nbpixelx/MACHINE_NUM))*nbpixely+ypixel]=iter;

Comment: yes, something like that. This is needed because your itertab buffer has only the size 1/2 of the global (i.e. the total, combined) size, but you are trying to index it using global indexes.

Comment: but i think if it was a problem of non allocated memory, it should show an error like segmentation fault, not just freezing?

Comment: now, i have did     "int sizebuffre=((nbpixelx*nbpixely));" so that al the buffer would ahave the some lenght, even if i will use juste the half in the itertabB and itertabA, when i run the program, i can see that the to thread start working, but they freez in the MPI_Send, i dont now why.

when i use the program just in the local, it work, but when i do parallelise in diferent machine, it don't work